# How can I format a prop in React-Native before displaying it?

Tags: react-native

If I have a prop that is equal to "8888888888" but I want to display "(888) 888-8888" as Text what is the best way to go about doing the conversion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare the function outside of the component, then pass the function in when needed:

```
function formatPhoneNumber(s) {
  var s2 = (""+s).replace(/\D/g, '');
  var m = s2.match(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/);
  return (!m) ? null : "(" + m[1] + ") " + m[2] + "-" + m[3];
}

var SampleApp = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
     <View style={styles.container}>
       <Text>{ formatPhoneNumber('5556065593') }</Text>
     </View>
    );
  }
});
```

You could also set a variable in the render function:

```
var SampleApp = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var number = formatPhoneNumber('5556065593')
    return (
     <View style={styles.container}>
       <Text>{ number }</Text>
     </View>
    );
  }
});
```

If you have the number as a prop, you could call it like this:

```
formatPhoneNumber(this.props.phonenumber)
```

Set up an example [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/HnDI3w).